# javascript stops working after link_to in rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a java script function that allow me to drag divs in my application.js

```
  $(function() {
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable();
  });
```

in my index file I have a bunch of divs with a draggable class,

```
    <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>

<div class="draggable">    
  <p><strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= task.title %></p>
  <p> <%= link_to 'Show', task, :class => 'text' %>
</div>
```

In addition each div also have a show option that allows me to go to a another page, the other pages have a back button that allow me to go back to my index page.

```
<%= link_to 'Back', tasks_url, :class => 'text' %>
```

but when I am going back to that page I can no longer drag the divs. If I refresh the page I can than drag the divs again.

is it a pipeline issue that I am not aware of ?

Comment: Are you using Rails 4 with default Turbolinks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Billy mentioned, sounds like Turbolinks, a feature that was new in Rails 4. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17600093/rails-javascript-not-loading-after-clicking-through-link-to-helper?rq=1) about how to work *with* Turbolinks or turn it off!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of this:

```
$(function() {
  $( ".draggable" ).draggable();
});
```

try this:

```
var ready = function() {             
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable();           
};                                   
$(document).ready(ready);            
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

Follow the reference here: [RailsCasts Turbolinks](http://railscasts.com/episodes/390-turbolinks)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like `application.js` is being cached, and, therefore, not executed again after going back. Try putting the js to initialize the draggables into the page itself, which should be executed still.

Comment: I tried putting it as a <script></script> in my code but it did not work