# javascript not working after click through link_to helper (heroku specific)

Tags: javascript, jquery, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I followed the instructions in this answer: [Rails, javascript not loading after clicking through link_to helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17600093/rails-javascript-not-loading-after-clicking-through-link-to-helper). Everything works perfectly for my local host, but my Heroku app encounters the same problem for whatever reason. I am using rails 4 and ruby 1.9.3, not sure why my particular app isnt loading the javascript.

I want to clarify that when refreshing the page and loading it initially the javascript works perfectly on my Heroku app. The specific problem is that when i click through to a page with javascript (that worked previously) with a link_to it fails to load.

Does anyone have any ideas? My issue is identical to the link I posted but I couldnt figure out how to get the fix to work on Heroku. The code I used in my fix is below:

```
jQuery ->  
ready = ->
  $('#products').dataTable
    sPaginationType: "full_numbers"
    bJQueryUI: true
    bProcessing: true
    bServerSide: true
    sAjaxSource: $('#products').data('source')


$(document).ready ready
$(document).on "page:load", ready
```