# jQuery replies Uncaught TypeError: $.tiggle_toc is not a functionon

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $.tiggle_toc is not a functiononclick @ 195:189
```

The code calling `tiggle_toc` is `onclick: "$.tiggle_toc()"` in a Rails
`link_to`.  Here is the javascript (cofeescript) which defines `tiggle_toc`:

```
  $.tiggle_toc = () ->
    console.log('TOGGLE TOC')
    $('.toc_level2').toggle()

  $('#toc_toggle').click ->
    $.tiggle_toc()
```

In another place I have

```
%span{title: 'Hide/show subsections', id: 'toc_toggle'}= link_to ETC
```

Thus clicking on this element in the browser will call `tiggle_toc`.
This works just fine.

The mystery (for me) is why in one case the call to `tiggle_toc` succeed
whereas in another case it does not.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Rails4 and is `tiggle_toc` inside a call to `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: Yes (Rails 4.0), `tiggle_toc` is inside `ready ->` which is called by `$(document).ready(ready)`.

Comment: Could it be something to do with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17600093/rails-javascript-not-loading-after-clicking-through-link-to-helper