# View bug when returning to root_path

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, owl-carousel

I'm encountering a bug with Owl Carousel and Ruby on Rails. When visiting the site, the carousel works as intended. However after following a link then returning to home the carousel breaks. I can't figure it out.
[Link](https://rails-tutorial-vickera.c9users.io/)

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".carousel").owlCarousel();
});
```

Ruby link:

```
<%= link_to "Subnuba", root_path %>
```

Carousel:

```
<div class="carousel">
  <div class='row'> 
  </div>
  <div class='row'> 
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It turns out it was a problem with the Turbolinks gem. See [Rails, javascript not loading after clicking through link_to helper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17600093/rails-javascript-not-loading-after-clicking-through-link-to-helper)