# Javascript DOM events before and after Turbolinks cache

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, turbolinks

Here I have:

```
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  console.log "page has loaded!"
  $ ->
    $("button#show-hide").click (e) ->
      e.preventDefault()
```

which makes my `click` event available only after Turbolinks caches page. I can do `$(document).on 'turbolinks:before-visit` which will make event available only before Turbolinks caches. How should I make event available at all times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you are binding to two events: `turbolinks:load` and `$(document).ready()`.

Turbolinks does not discard event listeners on the `document` so you can safely bind click handlers to it and they will be called scross page loads. From the Turbolinks documentation:

> When possible, avoid using the turbolinks:load event to add event listeners directly to elements on the page body. Instead, consider using event delegation to register event listeners once on document or window.

With this in mind, you can do:

```
$(document).on 'click', "button#show-hide", (e) ->
  e.preventDefault()
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you simply take the click event out of the 'turbolinks:load' and

'turbolinks:before-visit' context.

or If the button is added dynamically in the DOM, what you can do is attach a click handler to body and on click determine which element was clicked and proceed accordingly.

```
$('body').on('click','button#show-hide',function(){

});
```

In coffee script, you can do

```
$('body').on('click', 'button#show-hide', ( ->

));
```

**UPDATE**

From the answer on [Rails, javascript not loading after clicking through link_to helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17600093/rails-javascript-not-loading-after-clicking-through-link-to-helper)

If you want your click handlers to work on `page:change` and as well as on `ready` event you can do,

```
var ready = function() {
    // bind click handlers to DOM elements here
};

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:change', ready);
```

Comment: As from application.js - `//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .` I think because of this (turbolinks are being loaded first), my Js files where I bind to DOM elements does not work unless page reload

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17600093/rails-javascript-not-loading-after-clicking-through-link-to-helper

Comment: `ready` fire only in response to the initial page load—not after any subsequent page changes. So AFAIK, in my case it does the same as `load` that I tried before. But thanks for efforts

Comment: Well there is also  page:change event in the answer, both ready and page:change event call the ready function.

Comment: Nah, I think the problem is that you just can't bind to DOM event from Js/coffee file, so easily if Turbolinks does caching

Comment: I see, I am glad you got it working though using the inline click handler. :)

Comment: I hope someone will suggest a better answer, though :)

Comment: Yeah, you can also give this a read http://railscasts.com/episodes/390-turbolinks for reference.