# Rails Turbolinks - remove style before caching

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-5, turbolinks

I have this div:

```
<div class="hidden" id="more-items">
```

that I unhide/hide if click event happens:

```
<button type="button" onclick="showHide()">
```

Via:

```
@showHide = () ->
  $('div#more-items').toggleClass('hidden')
return
```

But problem is that div supposed to be closed after user comes back to the page. If he leaves it open, it remains open for 1 or 2 seconds after content loaded. Not sure at what stage it closes.

This doesn't help:

```
document.addEventListener 'turbolinks:before-cache', (e) ->
  $('div#more-items')[0].style.display = 'none'
return
```

as well as this:

```
document.addEventListener 'turbolinks:before-render', (e) ->
  e.data.newBody.getElementById('more-items').style.display = 'none'
return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is with the indentation of the `return`s. The Rails asset pipeline wraps each coffeescript file in an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE), so your compiled JavaScript would look like:

```
(function() {
  this.showHide = function() {
    return $('div#more-items').toggleClass('hidden');
  };

  return;

  document.addEventListener('turbolinks:before-cache', function(e) {
    return $('div#more-items')[0].style.display = 'none';
  });

  return;

}).call(this);
```

The outer function will `return` early and your `turbolinks:before-cache` code will never get run. CoffeeScript automatically returns the last line. If you want to return `undefined`, make sure your `return` is indented at the same level as your function's code.

Changing your coffeescript to the following should fix this:

```
@showHide = () ->
  $('div#more-items').toggleClass('hidden')

document.addEventListener 'turbolinks:before-cache', (e) ->
  $('div#more-items')[0].style.display = 'none'
```

---

To tidy things up a bit, you could do also the following:

HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="toggle-more">
```

CoffeeScript:

```
$(document).on 'click', '#toggle-more', ->
  $('#more-items').toggleClass('hidden')

$(document).on 'turbolinks:before-cache', ->
  $('#more-items').addClass('hidden')
```

Comment: Thx, nice post, but sadly I tried this. And I use inline listeners because as you can find in link below, Turbolink cache discards listeners from js - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46881883/javascript-dom-events-before-and-after-turbolinks-cache/46882334?noredirect=1#comment80721573_46882334

Comment: Turbolinks does not discard listeners on the document, just the body (and its children). I have tested this in a new Rails app and can confirm that it works :)

Comment: Ah, thats why... Thanks!